# Geography SQL type support in .NET Core 6 / Entity Framework Core

Tags: sql-server, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, nettopologysuite

I have a .NET Core 6 application and SQL Server database which has a table with a column defined as type `Geography`.

My goal is to use a Linq query to retrieve a list of rows where the Geography Distance < 4000 meters from a point.

The following T-SQL works fine:

```
-- SPATIAL WITHIN DISTANCE
DECLARE @Origin GEOGRAPHY,
        -- distance defined in meters
        @Distance INTEGER = 40000;        

-- center point
SET @Origin = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText('POINT(-93.5663 44.9033)', 4326);

-- return all rows from events in 40km radius
SELECT * FROM dbo.GeographyAreas WHERE @Origin.STDistance(Geography) <= @Distance;
```

I would prefer to implement this code in my application data layer and use LINQ syntax rather than a stored procedure using the above code.  But there seems to be a mismatch between SQL Server `Geography` column type and the spatial libraries Microsoft offers:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite
NetTopologySuite.Core
Microsoft.Spatial
Microsoft.SqlServer.Types
```

`NetTopologySuite` supports the `Geometry` type, but not `Geography` from what I see.

`Microsoft.Spatial` `Geography` type will not map to the SQL Server `Geography` type.

`Microsoft.SqlServer.Types` appears to be for .NET (classic) not .NET Core.

I am looking for something more like this:

```
public class GeographyAreas()
{
   public <SomeGeographyType> Geography { get; set; }
}

var origin = <SomeGeographyType>(-93.123, 44.456);
var dist = 40000;

List<GeographyAreas> results = _context.GeographyAreas.Where(x => x.Geography.Distance(origin) < dist).ToList();
```

where `<SomeGeographyType>` is a placeholder for any of these:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite
Microsoft.Spatial
```

When I use this approach I get an error:

> The Geography property of GeographicAreas.Geography could not be mapped because the database provider does not support this type

Is it possible to do this in Entity Framework Core or does it make sense to implement a stored procedure with the T-SQL code above?

Comment: What is wrong with this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/spatial)?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv there is no documentation that I am aware of that describes mapping of SQL Geography type to an EntityFrameworkCore type. This is not true for Geometry type; however Geometry will not suffice for my needs.

Looking closely at that documentation (which I studied carefully) you will not find useful guidance; only references to Geometry data type.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself.   As it turns out there is a video where the fact that the Geography aspect of NetTopologySuite is described.
It is intentionally left out (but the requirement solved in an admittedly roundabout way).

According to this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IHslY5rrxD0&list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oX-DBuRG4u58ZTAJgBAeQ-t&index=16) when creating the model in Entity Framework, the data type to use is Geometry (even for a Geography SQL Server data type).  The decision by the NetTopologySuite team was made to not add Geography-specific features because, in fact, the code used to work with Geography and Geometry is identical.  This is not to say that a globe-based Geography value is the same as a Cartesian-based Geometry one; just that the code to operate on them is the same.

I was in fact able to get this to work using LINQ query.   If interested I will post the full solution here.

Comment: Just to add to this, Geometry is the base type. It is better to use the correct derived type as the Property type e.g. if you are storing a geography Point in the DB then best to use Point, if LineString then LineString. These types and derived types are defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial#nettopologysuite